# How to integrate BillDesk Payment Gateway with Asp.Net Website?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a business website using Asp.net and have reached to Payment Options phase of the project. I want to integrate my website with BillDesk Payment Gateway but not finding any helpful documentation on internet to do so. Even failed to find any suitable help from the site of BillDesk. Can anyone please help me with proper documentation and example to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found one article [here](http://challadotnetfaq.blogspot.in/2011/10/integration-with-bill-desk-payment.html),  but this is also not compelete I guess to help me out with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact billdesk.

To contact click [here](http://www.billdesk.com/part_bill.htm) and run the demo

Also, refer [this](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1341-bill-desk-payment-gateway-integration-approach.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for Reply.. Will try to contact billdesk first. Hopefully I get proper guidance from them.

Comment: They ll give demo on their site